# sp_BlitzCache doesn't monitor databases under availability group

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzcache

I'm using the latest version of sp_BlitzCache to capture some performance issues and slow runnig queries, but it seems the sp doesn't check or monitor databases that belong to an availability group, other databases without always-on feature enabled being captured properly, the user that I'm running the script has full admin permission, any tips or solution?

Comment: Is it a read only replica that is being excluded? If so, that [is by design](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/fb5e8fff2284729661eee08aad5d7fa03e81b167/sp_BlitzCache.sql#L1576-L1581)

Comment: Correct, it is secondary, how can I capture long-running queries on secondary using  sp_BlitzCache? what is the limitation?

Comment: If it is not possible to use sp_BlitzCache to capture slow running or poor performance queries, is there any other similar scripts that I can run on secondary (with read-intent)?

Comment: @Sam your follow up comment isn't likely to get any attention. You should ask a new question to get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sp_BlitzCache skips Availability Group secondary databases by design. [This Github issue explains the issue that sp_BlitzCache hits](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/2072) when some of the databases aren't available for querying.